# QuickSearchJS with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, quick-search

I'm using QuickSearchJS and it is working as expected until ajax call is made and then it doesn't work. I have tried 2 ways. Is there a way to use it with document.on function or any alternate way?

1st way

```
$(function () {
    var qs = $('input#filterText').quicksearch('#a option')
});
```

2nd way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        var qs = $('input#filterText').quicksearch('#a option')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you should use `qs.cache();` after your ajax call.

```
var qs = $('input#id_search_list').quicksearch('ul#list_example li');
$('ul#list_example').append('<li>Loaded with Ajax</li>');
qs.cache();
```

```js
 var qs=$('input#search').quicksearch('table tbody td');

 $("#append").on("click", function(e) {
     $("tr").append('<td>'+$("#search").val()+'</td>');
     qs.cache();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.quicksearch/2.2.0/jquery.quicksearch.min.js"></script>
/* Example form */
<form>
    <input type="text" id="search">
    <input type="button" id="append" value="ajax">
</form>

/* Example table */
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test cell</td>
            <td>Another test cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```